# How much time does Sns takes to push a message to GCM/FCM? I

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

The notifications that I am sending are actually created using complex logic in java. With back end processing which includes two dB calls and a third party API call, I am able to send only 2.6 notifications/sec.If I remove this logic or simply push a generic text to a topic or devices , what will be the rise in this rate.
In the logs I can see that sns processes this notifications one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

It ranges between 2s and 4s per message (95th percentile).

I'm able to push about a million/minute by opening thousands of HTTP connections to Amazon SNS.

Comment: Thanks Krum, I am now at 3 message/second without any changes in the http endpoints.

Comment: I am trying to figure out an approximate avg time taken between the message getting published by sns and requestid being received by sns. Just between Sns and Gcm/fcm. No backend involved.